# How to loop through attributes in rails controller params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a has_many relationship and I want to loop a certain field on each of the items link to the main model (ingredients on a recipe).  Im trying to do this in before_filter so I can parse the users input correctly into what I want.  How can I set up the do loop to get the params I want

Comment: please post some data at least controller or model code

Comment: I don't think you want to do this in a `before_filter` hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request parameters in Rails are accessible via the `params` hash. You can loop over the hash using an iterator.

```
params.each do |k,v|
  puts "#{k}: #{v}"
end
```

As for parsing the user's input, I personally would not do that in a `before_filter` method. You gave an example below of converting input such as "1 1/2" to 1.5. Try something like this:

ingredient.rb:

```
# amount :decimal (assuming this column exists on the ingredients table)

def humanized_amount
  amount.humanize!
end    

def humanized_amount=(value)
  amount = cast_humanized_value_to_decimal(value)
end
```

Then use `humanized_amount` as the attribute for your form input. Just a suggestion. There's not really a right answer.

Comment: Ok so then do I want to just use an if check to find the keys I want and modify them

Comment: Yes; but again, I think you should reconsider your overall approach to the problem. Modifying the params hash is not a good idea.

Comment: Im open to suggestions, how should i go about modifying and formatting what users input to match what I want to store in the table.   For example trying to take a possible "1 1/2" and convert it to 1.5

Comment: See my latest answer revision. Good luck!

Comment: Ok...and Im assuming the humanized and cast_humanized_value_to_decimal() are just made up calls right?

Comment: Yes - those are made up calls.